# Show UIMenuController when MKAnnotationView was tapped

Tags: ios, swift

This is what I do in code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("selectedview")

    let controller = UIMenuController.shared
    let item = UIMenuItem(title: "Usun", action: #selector(deletePointer))
    controller.menuItems = [item]
    controller.setTargetRect(mapView.frame, in: mapView)
    controller.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}

@objc func deletePointer() {
    print("deleted")
}
```

but menu doesn't appear. Method is called because `selectedView` is printed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewController has to be able to become the first responder:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then set your target rect like this (where `view` is the annotationView):

```
controller.setTargetRect(view.frame, inView: mapView)
```

Sorry for my code being Swift 2 code... :)

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5.0, it should be:

```
extension  mapViewController
{

// Your View Controller
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool
{
    return true
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect annoView: MKAnnotationView )
{
    let controller = UIMenuController.shared
    let item = UIMenuItem(title: "Menu Test1", action: #selector(menuTestFunc))
    controller.menuItems = [item]

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *)
    {
        UIMenuController.shared.showMenu( from: self.view, rect: annoView.frame )
    }
    else
    {
        UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect( annoView.frame, in: self.view )
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible( true, animated: true )
    }
}


@objc func menuTestFunc()
{
    print( "menuTestFunc() called" )
}

} //    mapViewController extensions
```